# Creating a grunt file for an angular app

Tags: gruntjs

My directory structure looks like below:

```
--myapp/
   --client/
      --build/
      --css/
      --js/
          --angular/                         #angular libraries here
             --angular.js
              --angular-resource.js
              --angular-ui-router.js
           --jquery/                          #jquery libraries here
              --jquery.js
      --app.js
      --index.html

   --server/ #All server related files here
   --Gruntfile.js
```

My Grunt file so far looks like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
    concat: {
      dist: {
           src: ['client/js/angular/*.*] 
           dest: 'client/build/angular-build.js'
             }

}

});

};
```

This is as far as I have gotten. Don't see any easy grunt file tutorials on this.
Th ouput I am looking for is all angular libraries in one output file. All jquery libraries in another.. all css libraries in third.

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: Are you attempting to concatenate several source files into one large file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. You don't know it, but you're using [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat), so you'd better `npm install` that and `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');` it.
2. Concat doesn't support wildcards. This is good, because the order that these files are included is going to matter. `angular.js` must be included before `angular-resource.js`

I've included a rough template of what your Gruntfile needs to look like to accomplish this, but know that this is not the right way to do this. You should be loading your dependencies using something like [bower](http://bower.io/) and serving them individually, or using something like Browserify or Require.js. You'll come to see the value of that as the project progresses.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json');
    concat: {
        angular: {
            src: [
                'client/js/angular/angular.js',
                'client/js/angular/angular-resource.js',
                'client/js/angular/angular-ui-router.js'
            ]
            dest: 'client/build/angular-build.js'
        },
        jquery: {
            src: ['client/js/jquery/jquery.js']
            dest: 'client/build/jquery-build.js'
        },
        ...
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
};
```